# Twilio: how to get the subaccount of a phone number?

Tags: python, twilio

Is it possible that using the phone number I can get the sub account number that this phone number belongs to in Twilio?

I am using the following in python:

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

os.environ['account_sid'] = 'Master_account_SID'
os.environ['auth_token'] = 'Master_account_token'
account_sid = os.environ['account_sid']
auth_token = os.environ['auth_token']

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

incoming_phone_num = client.incoming_phone_numbers.list(phone_number='+1XXXXXXXXXX', limit=10)

print(incoming_phone_num.account_sid)
```

The above returns error "object has no attribute 'account_sid'"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is JavaScript but you will get the general idea from the explanation below.

```
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

const phoneNumberToSearch = '+1484xxxxxx';
let subAccount;

client.api.accounts.list({status: 'active', limit: 1000})
  .then(accounts => {
    accounts.forEach(a => {
      subAccount = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken, { accountSid: a.sid });
      subAccount.incomingPhoneNumbers
        .list({phoneNumber: phoneNumberToSearch, limit: 1})
        .then(incomingPhoneNumbers => {
          incomingPhoneNumbers.forEach(i => console.log(i.accountSid))
        });
    })
  });
```

API being used:

[REST API: Accounts](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/api/account)

- To list all the subaccounts
- Code Example: List All Active Accounts

[IncomingPhoneNumber resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource)

- To iterate through each subaccount looking for the number
- Code Example: Filter IncomingPhoneNumbers with exact match

[Making a phone call with a Subaccount](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/api/subaccounts#call-subaccounts)

- The structure to use the main project credentials for the sub-account
- Code Example: Make a call from a subaccount (to see how to call the client)

Comment: Thank you so much, I got the idea now.

Answer (score 0):

Following the same idea as Alan's answer but since you were writing python:

```py
from twilio.rest import Client

client = Client()

phoneNumber = '+1xxxxxxxxxx'

subaccounts = client.api.accounts.list(status='active', limit=1000)

for subaccount in subaccounts:
    subclient = Client(account_sid=subaccount.sid)
    numbers = subclient.incoming_phone_numbers.list(phone_number=phoneNumber, limit=1)
    if len(numbers) > 0:
        print(subaccount.sid, subaccount.friendly_name)
```

The key takeaway is that the phone numbers are only available in each subaccount so you need to loop through them to find the number you want.

Note that Twilio's python API will take credentials from environment variables itself so you didn't need to do that.